Is it Possibility to change font type in the Workshop module?
Can we add a new font family to the Workshop module for multiple widgets and modules I want to use a separate font family so do let me know if anyone has any idea about how to achieve that.
I'm not able to find any way to do that.

Palantir Foundry does not have multiple font options.
